# In Android, can the value of a custom attribute be changed at runtime?

Tags: runtime, android-custom-attributes

I know one can set custom attributes with their values on an xml, but,
can that value be changed later at runtime?

I have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:example="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/ValidatedButton.ValidatedButton"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <validatedbutton.ValidatedButton
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_selector"
        example:state_valid="false"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to change example:state_valid to true or false at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, however it's something that I've recently been trying to figure out as well.

As it happens to be, the release of the *Android MNC* sdk has given us a lot of neat abilities with the use of **Data Binding**. The official documentation and guide can be found ***[here](https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html)***, and a really good tutorial is available ***[here](http://www.androidauthority.com/android-m-data-binding-615674/)***.

I haven't actually explored this a lot, but I believe it's now possible to achieve the original question by using this new method. Lemme know if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

But below you can find ugly workaround:

I think you should distinguish two ways of building view:

1. Inflate ***static** layout from xml
2. Build it **on runtime** in Java

In constructor of your custom view you can obtain static attributes values defined in layout and save them in custom view class fields. Then values stored in fields are used to build  your view. View is build in some context (e.g. in context of activity), so theoreatically you can cast context to your custom activity and get information if you want change 'attribute value' or not, but you will change only Java variable, not xml value.

In my opinion if your view is so dynamic, that it will change really often, you should consider to place in XML just simple container (e.g. FrameLayout). Then build your view and add it to container on runtime.